# Keep from moving left and right when scrolling up and down

Tags: magic-trackpad

I just got a magic trackpad and when I scroll rapidly up and down the horizontal scrolling changes on me.  I mostly notice this in DBeaver.  Any ideas how to keep it from doing this?

Comment: Do you want to disable horizontal scrolling completely?

Comment: What do you mean with "the horizontal scrolling changes on me"?

Comment: What is happening is I am trying to look at values in a column that is in the middle of a page.  When there is room to scroll left and right it is very hard to scroll up and down without the column I am viewing from scrolling away.

Comment: Looks like another SQL DBA tool written using a Java IDE backend.  Must be extra sensitive when scrolling and the slightest movement side to side or at a less than perfectly vertical two finger swipe is causing horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Sounds like it is just the way it was written?  Apple specific apps like numbers don't seem to have this problem.